# Status bar labels turn white after setting UIWindow's rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, uiwindow, rootviewcontroller

Some times after doing this

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
    window.rootViewController = HomeTabBarController()
}
```

I get this kind of visual of status bar [status bar visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4xqh.jpg)

it doesn't happen always and when it happens it may stay for a while.
Should I live with it or is there anything I could change?

Comment: do you find solution for this?